# Circular button background and hint while performing a long click

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-appcompat, android-button

I've created an ImageButton which when I perform a long click on it, its background becomes black. How can I change its style from [image: this] to [image: this one]?

And also, how can I add [image: this brief hint] to the button while a long click is performed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        ../>
```

and:

```
    val imageButton : ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imagebutton)
    ViewCompat.setTooltipText(imageButton, "Tooltip")
```

Comment: Is there any alternative for tooltipText which can be used for API < 26?

Comment: @FaridRjb `ViewCompat.setTooltipText`

Comment: You can also set the tooltipText in xml using the android:tooltipText attribute. Source https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/tooltips